# Trouble Adding Web Service to VS2010 for SSRS CLR Stored Proc

Tags: reporting-services, clr, reportingservices-2005

I am attempting to reference the SSRS web service and it is not going as expected, please let me know what I'm doing wrong.
In VS 2010:
Step 1) Add Service Reference
Address=http://myserver/reportserver/reportservice2005.asmx?wsdl (server does not have a named instance)
name = ReportingServices2005_BETA

Step 2) Then in my clr_sproc I write:
     _
    Public Shared Sub TestMonkey2(RptName As SqlString,
                                  Params As SqlString,
                                  FileName As SqlString)
    Dim rs As New ReportingServices2005_BETA()

Result:
I get an error in the error list "Error 1 Type expected"

I can write these lines without error...
    Dim rs As New ReportingServices2005_BETA.Job
    Dim rs As New ReportingServices2005_BETA.Role
    Dim rs As New ReportingServices2005_BETA.Task
but those to not match all of the tutorials on the web?

I know I'm missing something simple...
thanks

Comment: Found my problem, I was adding a Service Reference instead of a Web Reference, problem solved.

Comment: Please add your "solution" as an answer and accept it (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16930/169697).

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, I was adding a Service Reference instead of a Web Reference, problem solved.

But in the long run, I found you cannot use ReportingServices2005 in a CLR due to security restrictions.  I'm back to the drawing board.

dang.